# consulta sql con condiciones

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysqli

tratando de resolver una solicitud de un cliente me he topado con un inconveniente y quería saber si es posible hacer una consulta sql con condicionales .

Mi problema es el siguiente en el momento tengo una consulta que me permite traer información de 3 tablas.

NGRESO: Es la tabla que tiene todos los equipos registrados (marca, serial, fecha de ingreso, ubicacion)

EQUIPO: Es la tabla que tiene la hoja de vida de los equipos, se almacena el indice de ingreso y el indice de movimiento ( si ha tenido movimientos de ubicacion) y el estado actual del equipo.

MOVIMIENTO: Es la tabla que guarda los cambios que se le han echo al equipo desde que ingreso al sistema hasta el momento actual.

---

mi problema  es que tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT equipo.mov_ide, ingreso.ciu_ide, ingreso.zona_ide, ingreso.ofi_ide, ingreso.micro_ide, ingreso.pun_ide, movimiento.ciu_ideD , movimiento.zona_ideD, movimiento.ofi_ideD, movimiento.micro_ideD, movimiento.pun_ideD, equipo.ide_equipo, ingreso.hard_ide, ingreso.af_fec, ingreso.mar_ide, ingreso.mod_ide,ingreso.ide_prov, ingreso.af_ser, ingreso.af_mac, ingreso.af_simcard, equipo.est_equi
FROM equipo 
LEFT JOIN ingreso ON (equipo.ide_ing = ingreso.ing_ide AND equipo.ide_equipo = ingreso.ide_equipo) 
LEFT JOIN movimiento ON (equipo.mov_ide = movimiento.mov_ide AND equipo.ide_equipo = movimiento.ide_equipo)
```

y me trae estos resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Ahora mi problema radica en que como se ve en la imagen si el primer campo
`equipo.mov_ide` es mayor a `0` quiere decir que el equipo tuvo algun movimiento en la ubicacion  y esta se almacenara en `movimiento.ciu_ideD , movimiento.zona_ideD, movimiento.ofi_ideD, movimiento.micro_ideD, movimiento.pun_ideD` si por el contrario el equipo no tiene movimientos y el primer campo es cero .. las posiciones mostradas quedan `NULL`.

Se podria hacer una consulta que traiga solo la ubicacion del equipo real .
en este caso si el primer campo `equipo.mov_ide` es `0`
la ubicacion real  son los primeros campos `ingreso.ciu_ide, ingreso.zona_ide, ingreso.ofi_ide, ingreso.micro_ide, ingreso.pun_ide`

si el primer campo `equipo.mov_ide` es mayor a `0`
la ubicación real es  respecto a movimiento `movimiento.ciu_ideD , movimiento.zona_ideD, movimiento.ofi_ideD, movimiento.micro_ideD, movimiento.pun_ideD`

*ILUSTRACION*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero que todo, te insto a que te acostumbres a usar alias en las tablas; esto mejora la lectura de la consulta y hace más fácil entenderla.

Sobre tu pregunta, suena a que necesitas simplemente una expresión `CASE`:

```
SELECT  e.mov_ide, 
        CASE WHEN e.mov_ide = 0 THEN i.ciu_ide ELSE m.ciu_ideD END ciu_ide, 
        CASE WHEN e.mov_ide = 0 THEN i.zona_ide ELSE m.zona_ideD END zona_ide, 
        CASE WHEN e.mov_ide = 0 THEN i.ofi_ide ELSE m.ofi_ideD END ofi_ide, 
        CASE WHEN e.mov_ide = 0 THEN i.micro_ide ELSE m.micro_ideD END micro_ide, 
        CASE WHEN e.mov_ide = 0 THEN i.pun_ide ELSE m.pun_ideD END pun_ide, 
        e.ide_equipo, 
        i.hard_ide, 
        i.af_fec, 
        i.mar_ide, 
        i.mod_ide,
        i.ide_prov, 
        i.af_ser, 
        i.af_mac, 
        i.af_simcard, 
        e.est_equi
FROM equipo e
LEFT JOIN ingreso i
    ON e.ide_ing = i.ing_ide 
    AND e.ide_equipo = i.ide_equipo
LEFT JOIN movimiento m
    ON e.mov_ide = m.mov_ide 
    AND e.ide_equipo = m.ide_equipo
;
```

Comment: Exactamente eso necesitaba!... gracias !!